# Grouping hierarchical content in QGIS legend: Rule symbology, split layers or?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a layer with different grouped elements. Lets say you would create an ice-cream-map, where polygons represent the dominant type. You could categorize the world firstly in cream and sorbet parts. Within those parts, you would differentiate the flavours like banana or chocolate in cream and lemon or berry in sorbet. I would like to represent this hierarchy in the legend too. So instead of having the categories "banana cream", "chocolate cream" etc. I would like to have a layer title "Ice cream world", the subtitles "cream" and "sorbet" respectively, and below the flavors. To complicate things: In real life I have three levels. The following approaches work, but seem to me like workarounds

- multiple layers from the same dataset, each of which representing a fraction, grouped together.
- Applying a rule based symbology with groups. This comes very close to what I think we would need, but the grouping is not reflected in the legend. Furthermore, I think we'll run into troubles saving this as a layer style and applying it to data with slightly differently labelled attributes.

Below a screenshot from the legend as well as from the layer view.

Any idea on how to solve that?

[image: Example]
[image: layer view]